# JQuery clear divs when click off input but not off page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying clear a div when a user clicks or tabs off of an input, but I don't want the div cleared if the user changes to a different window or browser tab.

What I have so far clears the div in both cases:

```
$input.on('blur focus mousedown', function () {
  $input.val("");
  $("#cors-test-invalid").html("");
  $("#cors-test-views").html("");
  $("#cors-test-workbooks").html("");
  $("#cors-test-datasources").html("");
  $("#cors-test-projects").html("");
  $("#cors-test-users").html("");
});
```

Comment: You can shorten the div part with the starts-with-selector: `$( "div[id^='cors-test']" ).html( "" );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
$(document.body).on('click',function(){
//here its a click on body which eliminates the other tabs or windows
if(!$input.is(":focus"))
{
//here element doesnt have focus, so we are good to do the logic
  $input.val("");
  $("#cors-test-invalid").html("");
  $("#cors-test-views").html("");
  $("#cors-test-workbooks").html("");
  $("#cors-test-datasources").html("");
  $("#cors-test-projects").html("");
  $("#cors-test-users").html("");

}

});
```

Comment: This solution is great. This is nit picky but if you know how to do this it would be great. Is there a way to put the action on the whole page and not just the body? The body of the site doesn't span the whole width (design decision)

Comment: I think document would do, but try it first. @anton2g